Kubernetes and Gunicorn health check issues
I currently have an application that uses fastapi + gunicorn on a production server.
It runs with 3 async workers, and it can only have that many workers.
This application receives hundreds of requests per second, and this causes the workers to be almost always busy with some task, so when the Kubernetes health check system tries to make an internal request to the application and is unable to do so (because all workers are busy), Kubernetes forces the container to restart because it thinks there is no availability.
Have you ever had a similar use case? What did you do to resolve this situation?

Which signals do you want to use to separate "does not respond to users because it's too busy" and "does not respond to users because it's broken"? Having a separate app inside the container that polls the state of the other app and exposes that as a /health endpoint could be an option in that case - i.e. the /health endpoint responds based on some metric you evaluate inside the second app.
